# Height of button child element behaving differently in Safari than in Chrome

Tags: css, button, safari, flexbox, webkit

I'm trying to code a single-column, full-height nav, using equal-height button elements with child elements for styling. This works fine in Chrome & Firefox, but not Safari/Webkit. Example here:

https://codepen.io/mattsims/pen/BaKyNye

```
<div class="columns">

  <div class="column">

    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="navigation-outer">
        <div class="navigation-inner">

          <button class="navigation-button reset">
            <span class="icon-button-outer">
              <span class="icon-button-inner">
                <span class="content">Button</span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </button>

          <button href="#" class="navigation-button reset">
            <span class="icon-button-outer">
              <span class="icon-button-inner">
                <span class="content">Button</span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </button>

          <button href="#" class="navigation-button reset">
            <span class="icon-button-outer">
              <span class="icon-button-inner">
                <span class="content">Button</span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </button>

          <button href="#" class="navigation-button reset">
            <span class="icon-button-outer">
              <span class="icon-button-inner">
                <span class="content">Button</span>
              </span>
            </span>
          </button>

        </div><!-- /navigation-inner -->
      </div><!-- /navigation-outer -->
    </div><!-- /navigation -->

  </div><!-- /column -->

</div><!-- /columns -->
```

*(see above Codepen link for CSS)*

As demonstrated, using anchors instead of buttons resolves the issue, but as this is to be used in an SPA, buttons are required/preferred.

Any help to stop me tearing the last of my hair out will be very much appreciated!

Comment: do you need this dom structure or we are allowed to add/remove elements?